# Why does this code fragment compile with VS2010 but not GCC 4.5.2?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, gcc, bind

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar() { std::cout << "Foo::Bar" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
    function<void(Foo*)> f1(bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1));
    function<void(shared_ptr<Foo>)> f2(bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1));
    return 0;
}
```

GCC objects to the second bind statement being assigned to the function object with the shared_ptr signature. Here is the error output.

> /usr/include/c++/4.5/functional:2103|6|instantiated from
>   ‘std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::function(_Functor, typename
>   std::enable_if<(! std::is_integral<_Functor>::value),
>   std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes ...)>::_Useless>::type) [with _Functor =
>   std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>)>, _Res
>   = void, _ArgTypes = {std::shared_ptr}, typename std::enable_if<(!
>   std::is_integral<_Functor>::value), std::function<_Res(_ArgTypes
>   ...)>::_Useless>::type =
>   std::function)>::_Useless]’|
>   /home/craig/work/litd/test/main.cpp:29|97|instantiated from here|
>   /usr/include/c++/4.5/functional|1713|error: no match for call to
>   ‘(std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>)>)
>   (std::shared_ptr)’| ||=== Build finished: 1 errors, 0 warnings
>   ===|

Edit:
More mystery, when I change the include headers to their tr1 equivalents, it does compile.

```
#include <tr1/functional>
#include <tr1/memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std::tr1;

class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar() { std::cout << "Foo::Bar" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
    function<void(Foo*)> f1(bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1));
    function<void(shared_ptr<Foo>)> f2(bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might help to post the actual error message, too.

Comment: It might need help with the template `std::function<void(typename std::shared_ptr<Foo>)> f2(bind(&Foo::Bar, std::placeholders::_1));` perhaps?

Comment: Still not happy. /home/craig/work/litd/test/main.cpp||In function ‘int main()’:|
/home/craig/work/litd/test/main.cpp|29|error: typedef declaration invalid in parameter declaration|
/home/craig/work/litd/test/main.cpp|29|error: expected ‘::’ before ‘f2’|
/home/craig/work/litd/test/main.cpp|29|error: ‘std::function<void()>::f2’ has not been declared|
/home/craig/work/litd/test/main.cpp|29|error: expected ‘)’ before ‘(’ token|
||=== Build finished: 4 errors, 0 warnings ===|

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a bug in g++'s implementation of `std::function` or maybe `std::bind`, depending on whether you can invoke the object returned by `bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1)` with `foo`; if this works:

```
auto fn2 = bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1);
fn2(foo);
```

then it would seem that g++'s `std::function` implementation is incomplete. Otherwise, it would seem that the implementation of `std::bind` is incomplete.

[20.8.9.1.2] Function template `bind` states:

> ```
> template<class F, class... BoundArgs>
>   unspecified bind(F&& f, BoundArgs&&... bound_args);
> ```
>
> ...
>
> *Returns*: A forwarding call wrapper `g` with a weak result type (20.8.2). The effect of `g(u1, u2, ..., uM)` shall be `INVOKE(fd, v1, v2, ..., vN, result_of::type)`

[20.8.2] Requirements states:

> Define `INVOKE(f, t1, t2, ..., tN)` as follows:
>
> — `(t1.*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of type `T` or a reference to an object of a type derived from `T`;
>
> — `((*t1).*f)(t2, ..., tN)` when `f` is a pointer to a member function of a class `T` and `t1` is not one of the types described in the previous item;
>
> ...

When binding `&Foo::Bar`, the returned "forwarding call wrapper" takes one argument, `u1`. Call its type `U1`. Further on in [20.8.9.1.2] it states that because the 1st template argument type in `BoundArgs` was the `_1` placeholder type, the type `V1` is `U1&&`.

Passing a `std::shared_ptr<Foo>` to the forwarding call wrapper returned by `bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1)` should be allowed because case 2 of [20.8.2] applies.

**EDIT:** I am using the same version of g++ as you, 4.5.2, on Windows (MinGW). For me, the following compiles just fine:

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
public:
    void Bar() { std::cout << "Foo::Bar" << std::endl; }
};

int main()
{
    shared_ptr<Foo> foo(new Foo);
    function<void(Foo*)> f1(bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1));
    //function<void(shared_ptr<Foo>)> f2(bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1));
    auto fn2 = bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1);
    fn2(foo);
    return 0;
}
```

<s>It thus appears to be g++'s implementation of `std::function` that is to blame.</s>

**EDIT2:** The following fails:

```
auto fn2 = bind(&Foo::Bar, placeholders::_1);
fn2(std::shared_ptr<Foo>(foo));
```

> SO7408263.cpp:19:31: error: no match for call to '(std::_Bind(std::_Placeholder<1>)>) (std::shared_ptr)'

Perhaps it's `std::bind` after all.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Strange, it does not compile on my Ubuntu setup. Could different bits be broken on each platform?

Comment: @Craig: `fn2(foo);` does not compile on your Ubuntu setup? Strange. I thought that MinGW's version of libstdc++ is unmodified.

Answer (score 0):

The function will expect `->*` to be overloaded to use a pointer-to-member. I believe that `shared_ptr` does not provide this functionality. The TR1 specification might have mandated a specialization but the C++11 might not. In Visual Studio then the C++11 `shared_ptr` is defined to be their TR1 versions, which would explain the difference.

Comment: I have looked at both the g++ & vs2010 implementations of shared_ptr and neither seem to implement operator ->*.

Comment: @Craig: I also mentioned the possibility of a specialization.